# using functions of an included file makes coldfusion forget imports. Is this normal?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfimport

I noticed that when I call a function of a previously included (cfinclude) .cfm file, all the coldfusion imports (cfimport) that have happened at this point are forgotten. It's like you haven't imported anything. I found this very strange behavior so I've isolated it, but the results stayed the same, even in coldfusion 10.

My setup:

/example

- functions.cfm
- index.cfm
- /components

  - MyCFC.cfc

functions.cfm:

```
<cfscript>
  function test(){
    return "test";
  }
</cfscript>
```

components/MyCFC.cfc:

```
component  output="false"{}
```

index.cfm:

```
<cfscript>
  include "functions.cfm";
  import components.MyCFC;

  foo = test();
  bar = new MyCFC();
</cfscript>
```

This code will throw a coldfusion error : "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface MyCFC".
when `foo = test();` is removed or placed after `bar = new MyCFC();`, the code runs just fine.

It doesn't matter if the import is placed before or after the include. Whenever an included function is called, the imports are forgotten.

Is this this a bug or is it supposed to behave this way?

Tested in coldfusion 9,0,0,251028 and coldfusion 10,282462

Comment: Why are you naming your CFC component with a `.cfm` file extension?  Does your code behave differently if the component MyCFC has a `.cfc` file extension?

Comment: It's a typo, sorry. Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected it

Comment: Also, the import statement ends with a (); I don't see that usage documented in the CF docs. Also, do you get the same error when you use foo=test(); rather than test=test(); . Just wondering about something messing up the scope resolver

Comment: That was also a typo. Corrected it, sorry.I tried changing test = test() to foo = test() but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is your CFC in a folder relative to your index.cfm called "components"? Just making sure your importing correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is. I've put it in a different folder, otherwise the import wouldn't be necessary. The code works if I remove `foo = test();` or place it under `bar = new MyCFC();`.

Comment: I am assuming the `import` is just the cfscript way of using `cfimport`, right?  Did you see this in the [docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ea1.html):  The cfimport tag must be on the page that uses the imported tags. For example, if you use a cfimport tag on a page that you include with the cfinclude call, you cannot use the imported tags on the page that has the cfinclude tag.  ColdFusion does not throw an error in these situations, but the imported tags do not run.For more information, see the Java Server Page 1.1 spec.

Comment: Yes, `import` is the cfscript alternative for `<cfimport>`. I also read that section on the online docs, but this code meets this requirement. The import happens in the same file that creates an instance of the imported file. And the import really works without the `foo = test();` line.

Comment: Calling a function shouldn't have any effect on importing, so this certainly sounds like a bug... https://bugbase.adobe.com

Comment: I've run my own test and come up with the same thing when trying to use import directly in the view. However, when I use this code in my controller I do not get an error. My guess is that it could certainly be related to including a page, but it more likely has to do with the mapping of the CFC. What does your application file structure look like?

Comment: I've editted this question and included the file structure. I'ts very basic. 'components' refers to the 'components' folder. No custom mappings are used in this example.

Comment: I haven't tested it on 9.0.2, only on 9.0.0 and 10. They both errored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do a lot of imports, I recently met some odd behavior and reported it do the CF9-bugbase:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3288035

ColdFusion resolves the imports only for the current file and whenever you call a different file, it's like the "execution context" switches to that files with it's imports. So in your case when you execute *new* ColdFusion looks in *functions.cfm* for the imports. When you then call a method of the current file, it switches back and finds the import.

If I am right, your code should work, if you execute `bar = new MyCFC();` directly after the import. Or you could define another method in the *index.cfm* and call it, before you create the class.

To work around that bug you need to make sure, that the import is resolved (on first use in the objects lifecycle) before that "context switching" takes place. So call `new MyCFC();` before the external method.

@Adobe: Would be nice to fix this;)

Comment: Wow, you're right. If I add a function to index.cfm and call that function after I called the test() function from the included file, the import works again. The strange behavior has become more clear to me now, thanks. (Still an annoying bug unfortunately)

Comment: I've added a note on the bug report referring to your bug id

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @PeterBoughton, this sounds like a bug. I couldn't find a similar bug being reported either so I would go ahead with submitting it. In the mean time if you scrap "import", you should still be able to reference the CFC using:

```
bar = new components.MyCFC();
```

Great catch!